# Scrollbar goes down the page

Tags: html, css, jsp, scrollbar

I have a jsp page where html code has been used with divs;I want to add scrollbar in all cases, so i have used this css code:

```
<body style="overflow: scroll; height : 90%">
```

a scroll bar is displayed in all case but it goes down the page i cant see the down icon of scroll bar,
It works fine in chrome but not in IE.Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see.. element 90% is always going to be 90% in case you set max-height;

```
<body>
<div style="overflow: scroll; height : 90%; max-height:500px">
```

Because if screen height is 1000px body tag = 900px, if you resize screen to 500px body will be 90% of 500px = 450px; always resizing. so after you set max height ( and probably you should set min-height depends what results you need ) if screen height will be 1000, but body max-height will be 500px it will become scrollable element.

And yea.. I checked first before posting here, so as you see to get work you should set to element like div (or other which contains display:block; ) to get it work :)
Hope I helped to solve problem, if yes, click solved + rep thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scroll vertically only you should try

> overflow-y:scroll

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: i have already that option, still the down icon doesn't fit into the page.